# ms loadtest from another project / dll

Tags: c#, load-testing

I'm trying to use unit tests from project `UnitProj` which contain many unit tests inside (and compiled as a class library) in `LoadProj` which should use those unit tests inside a `.loadtest`.

Unfortunately, I don't see my unit tests inside the dialog of loading tests:

[image]

I have added the folder containing the compiled dll to my `.testsettings` file

[image]